# El Capitan - Weather search in Spotlight not working

Tags: macos, spotlight, settings

I've just upgraded my Mac to OS X El Capitan and typed:

`weather in Sao Paulo, BR`

I got nothing.

I'm actually in Sao Paulo, Brazil. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From testing on my Mac, I can confirm that `weather in Sao Paulo, BR` doesn't actually show the weather, whereas `weather in Sao Paulo`, or `weather in Sao Paulo, Brazil` does. Whether or not the `ã` is used doesn't affect the result:

[image: natural language testing]

If these inputs don't return the natural language search results, then check on the [OS X Feature Availability page](https://www.apple.com/osx/feature-availability/#spotlight-natural-language). You may need to **reconfigure your Language & Region settings in System Preferences** in order to use the feature, until it's supported for your current Language and Region settings.

If neither of these methods provide solutions, you may want to try **disabling and reenabling Spotlight Suggestions**.

1. Open System Preferences & navigate to `Spotlight`

[image]

2. Ensure that `Spotlight Suggestions` is checked; if it's already checked, uncheck spotlight suggestions, then recheck it. Now, try bringing up Spotlight and you should be able to get the weather from typing `weather in sao paulo`

[image]